# Xamarin Android - Toolbar issue

Tags: xamarin.android

I am trying to add toolbar with menu items and overflow button, but buttons are not showing up and I am not sure why:

Included toolbar to my axml file:

```
<include          
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"          
    layout="@layout/toolbar" />
```

Added following code to `.cs` file into `OnCreate()` method:

```
var toolbar = FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);   
SetActionBar(toolbar);
ActionBar.Title = "My Toolbar";
```

Added menu folder under Resources and created `menu_doc.xml` file and placed following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item        
         android:id="@+id/menu_edit"        
         android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_content_create"        
         android:showAsAction="ifRoom"        
         android:title="Edit" />
     <item        
         android:id="@+id/menu_save"             
         android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_content_save"        
         android:showAsAction="ifRoom"        
         android:title="Save" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_preferences"        
        android:showAsAction="never"        
        android:title="Preferences" />
</menu>
```

Added following two functions after `OnCreate` method:

```
public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu) {     
    MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.top_menus, menu);     
    return base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item) {     
    Toast.MakeText(this, "Action selected: " + item.TitleFormatted,         
    ToastLength.Short).Show();     
    return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

When I run it - there is a toolbar with Title but it does not have any buttons. Please help. [image: Here is what I have]

Comment: If you use Visual Studio v15.7.x, there is new template that write all codes that you need to have, you can use that or learn from that

Comment: I am using 15.6.7

Comment: Sadly the template added in v15.7, can you update to latest version?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't now but thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

It seems a little bit late, but I fixed the same problem by adding app namespace with:

`xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

and changing `android:showAsAction` to `app:showAsAction`